# Form can't be saved in form editor after moving form definition into extension

Tags: typo3

After moving a form defintion to my own extension I cannot save the form definition.

I get this error message

The form could not be saved: The file

> "EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Forms/bewerbung.form.yaml" could not be saved: >Undefined index: yamlSettingsOverrides

Here is my custom form setup

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      persistenceManager:
        allowedExtensionPaths:
          10: EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Forms/
        allowSaveToExtensionPaths: true
        allowDeleteFromExtensionPaths: true

        renderingOptions:
          translation:
            translationFile:
              # Default translation file for the frontend:
              10: 'EXT:form/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf'
```

Initially i got complaining about Undefined Index: _LOCAL_LANG, so I added the default translation file in my custom form yaml definition, and it disappeared, it seems it is not "inherited" from the BaseConfiguration. Am I missing another piece of yaml?

Could someone please give a hint, what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After a composer update with all dependecies this error disappeared. Form Extension wasn't updated, so I think there was a buggy dependency.